# Reading task from a MS Project file

Tags: c#, ms-project, mpxj

I'm using MPXJ in order to read the tasks of a MS Project file. The file is hierarchically organized this way:

```
PROJECT
    Phase
        Task
```

I mean, they use `Summary Task` to organize the Project file.

My question is if I can differentiate the task of the PROJECTS and Phases, I mean, if I can differentiate task from `Summary Task` at the moment of read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Boolean property on the task object called "Summary". If it's set to true its a summary task.